# Determine whether or not the following functions are totally multiplicative. Explain your reasoning.

Tags: number-theory

Here is the question:
[image]

Here is my work:
[image]

For part a. I am confused on how to set up the beginning of my "proof" where I am supposing things.

For part b. I am confused on how to set up my "suppose" part as well as how f(m)f(n)= f(mn) is okay in part b but not okay in part  a.

Comment: Not following your logic.  For the first one, in order to be  totally multiplicative we'd need $f(1)=f(1\times 1)=f(1)\times f(1)$ (among other things).  Does that relation hold?

Comment: Why are you supposing multiplicativity at the beginning? Seems weird, given that you don’t prove it or use it.

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to (a) is fine apart from your conclusion:

$f(2.3)\ne f(2)f(3)$ and therefore $f$ is not multiplicative. Note that @Lulu's example is even easier.

In part (b) you correctly obtain the result that $f(mn)= f(m)f(n)$ for all positive integers $m$ and $n$. So therefore  $f$ is completely multiplicative.